# FuelPHP ORM condition ordery_by on a has_one relation

Tags: orm, fuelphp

I am not sure how I can explain this properly, but here I go.

http://prntscr.com/73w5af

In fuel, I am trying to arrange my has_many output based on a field in has_one relation of the has_many model. The left is the model with has_many with the order_by and the right is with the has_one. Basically, my Model_Hugot_Index has a field updated_at.

When I do the one you see in the screenshoot, I get an invalid for_each error when I extract my result in the has_many. Is there something I need to do for this to work?

I hope I explained this properly.

Answer (score 0):

`order_by` is a nested array:

```
'order_by' => array(
   array('field', 'order'),
   array('otherfield', 'order'),
),
```

because you can order on more than one column.

You get a foreach error because it finds a string as first element of the array, and not an array...